# What is the function that returns the private key?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

What is the function that returns the private key **d** if I know:

1. The Two primes numbers **(q, p)**
2. a selected public key **e**.

In an RSA algorithm?

Comment: If you don't want the explicit algorithm, but rather a function to call, then this question belongs on stackoverflow. It's also a good idea to decide what language you want this to work for.

Comment: Do you want an algorithm or the name of a function in some software package? I'm not sure there's an explicit function implemented for precisely this, but modular inverses are implemented in various packages for various languages, and that's just what you need, the modular inverse of $e$ with respect to $(p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: @Arthur Please explain the mathematical algorithm. I really need it

Comment: @DanielFischer Please explain the mathematical algorithm. Question edited.

Comment: You could see my answer from yesterday [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973176/how-can-i-calculate-the-n-th-root-of-a-number-modulo-m/1973189#1973189), which, while not specifically tailored to RSA, will tell you most of what you need. Or the links in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In RSA, $d$ must be the inverse of $e$ modulo $(p-1)(q-1)$. Various algorithms to compute [modular inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) exist; the most common one is a simple extension of *Euclid's algorithm* for computing the greatest common divisor of $e$ and $(p-1)(q-1)$.

There are code examples to be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).